# Unexpected exception from XDocument constructor

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

This works fine:

```
XDocument xdoc = new XDocument(
   new XDeclaration("1.1", "UTF-8", "yes"),
   new XProcessingInstruction("foo", "bar"),
   new XElement("test"));
```

However if I change it to pass the "params array" explicitly as an array:

```
object[] content = new object[] {
   new XDeclaration("1.1", "UTF-8", "yes"),
   new XProcessingInstruction("foo", "bar"),
   new XElement("test")
};
xdoc = new XDocument(content);
```

It fails with:

> System.ArgumentException: Non white space characters cannot be added to content.

Aren't these two examples exactly equivalent? What's going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use the first method, you're using the overload of XDocument that first takes an XDeclaration and then a params for the content. However, when you're using the second approach, you're using the overload which takes a params for content. The XDeclaration in your object[] array is coming through as content, and that's where it's blowing up.

See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xdocument.aspx

Comment: I see; I didn't realize I was calling different overloads. It's seems a bit unfortunate that the `XDocument(object[])` accepts all sorts of objects but for some reason excludes XDeclaration.

Comment: I wonder if the language designers would change the implementation of `params` args now if given the chance. This is a non-obvious pitfall that would be avoided if it could be indicated explicitly that you're passing varargs at the call site somehow.ll

Answer (score 21):

You can get this error when parsing XML strings if you use the `XDocument` constructor instead of a factory method.

Given:

```
var xmlString = "<some-xml />";
```

This fails:

```
var doc = new XDocument(xmlString);
```

This works:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
```

Comment: This was EXACTLY the issue I was having.  Thanks Drew!